# The question on configuring build path which involves a lot of libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

For a newly created project B, I need to build the path the exactly same way as an existing project A. After opening the “java build path” window by clicking “build path--> configure path”, I found that There are a lot of libraries involved in Project A. How to handle this kind of scenario? Add those jar files one-by-one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can locate all those jars on your file system/network, the best thing for you to do is to create an eclipse User Library.

### Creating a Library

```
Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Build Path >> User Libraries
```

- Select New
- Give your library a name
- Ok
- Select Add Jars
- Add all the jars you need for your library

With this library created, you can share the same jars between projects easily by importing the library as opposed to each individual jar file.

### Importing a Library

For each project that needs a particular library all you have to do is import the library.

- Open the project's properties
- Select Java Build Path
- Select Libraries tab
- Select Add library
- Select user Library
- Select your Library you created
- Finish

#### Note

User Libraries do not belong to projects, they belong to the User but can be referenced by multiple projects.

Using libraries allows you to update your jars only once for all projects that share the same jars.

I hope that helps :D

Comment: Hi, did you mean that this "user library" should be created on the exisiting project? Then for the newly created project, how can I get access to this user library?

Comment: No, libraries are not created on any projects they belong to eclipse/the user. 
I updated my answer to make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse and you want your new project to have the exact same libraries/dependencies as a previous project, you can copy the appropriate contents of the `.classpath` file from the old project to the new one.

This would include any `classpath` elements with a `kind="lib"` attribute.  You may have to update the `path` attribute if the location is relative.

This assumes you aren't using something like Maven for dependency management...

Comment: Where can I find this .classpath file? Thanks

Comment: Should be in the same folder as the Eclipse project. But @gotomanners answer of creating a User Library is probably better for the long-term, especially if you will be reusing the same dependencies many times.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

Create a User Library.

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries
```

The good thing about this is, you can re-use it provided you need exact set of libraries for other projects.
Bad thing is, if you want to add new JARs to this, you have to modify it. And modifications is .....not difficult, but takes time. Also, if you need slightly different set of JArs for different projects, then either you have to add some not-needed JARs in either/both projects or you have to add this User Library + some external JARs.

**EDIT 1**

1. Go into the Eclipse `preferences > Java > User Libraries`. Click on "New.."
2. Choose a name for your user library. Leave the "`System Library`" checkbox unchecked. Push "`OK`".
3. Select your library and click "`Add JARs...`". Navigate to the location where you put the library.
4. For each JAR file, there are 4 additional parameters you can attach to the JAR: Source location, Javadoc location, Native library location, and access rules. Except the rest 3, `Native library location` is not an optional field, and must be included if the JAR requires one

**OR**

Simply add as `External JARs`.

Good thing: Simple, straightforward.
Bad thing: If you need too many jars, you have to keep track of each separately.

Comment: I followed the procedure, Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries. But the system does not allow me to input the name into the window of "Defined User Libraries" and the button of "Export" is also disabled. Hence, I cannot create an user library for the exisiting project and export it. Can you let me know why? Thanks.